# Issue on Adding Before After Content to hr Element

Tags: html, css

I used to was able to add content to before and after of `hr` element by following rules. but it is not working now! can you please let me know what is causing the issue?

```css
.hr-title:before {
    content: "";
    width: 16px;
    height: 24px !important;
    background-color: gold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -1px;
}

.hr-title {
    position: relative;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #d0d0d0;
    color: #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 50%;
}

.hr-title:after {
    content: "";
    width: 4px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: #24A2C6;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    right: -1px;
}
```

```html
<h2> Test </h2>
<hr class="hr-title">
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is regarding to the specification of HTML `<hr />` is a so called `void` element. And the pseudo classes `::before` and `::after` aren't intended to work on `void`-elements. because those are elements whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances. Your example will only work in a few browsers which simply ignore the specification at that point.

You can find a list of `void` elements [**here**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#void-elements).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work properly. The objects before and after hr are both moved up to 7 px.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right just need to add this css **overflow: visible;** property in **.ht-title** class because of **hr** element has by default **overflow:hidden**. I hope this snippet will help.

```css
.hr-title {
  position: relative;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  color: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: visible;
}
.hr-title:before {
  content: "";
  width: 16px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: gold;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -1px;
}
.hr-title:after{
  content: "";
  width: 4px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #24A2C6;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  right: -1px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test</h2>
<hr class="hr-title">
```